# Inconsistent spacing between buttons across browsers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, cross-browser

**Razor Syntax**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Delivery Date <span class="tip" title="@deliveryDateTooltip">?</span></span>
    @Html.TextBox("DeliveryDate", Model.DeliveryDate.ToShortDateString(), "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield form-control", @data_key = "delivery-date", @data_original = Model.DeliveryDate.ToShortDateString(), @style = "width: 250px; max-width: 250px;" })
    @Html.TextBox("DayOfWeek", Model.DeliveryDate.DayOfWeek.ToString(), "{0}", new { @class = "dowfield form-control", @data_key = "delivery-date", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width: 132px; max-width: 132px;" })
    <button name="Clear" type="reset" class="btn btn-info" title="Clear the filter critera." data-monitor="ClearButton" style="border-radius: 0;">Clear</button>
    <button name="Filter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="Load the order according to the filter criteria." data-monitor="LoadButton" style="border-radius: 0;@(isIE ? "margin-left: -4px;" : "")">Load</button>
</div>
```

**Chrome**

Chrome looks perfectly fine and behaves exactly how I would expect.

[image: Chrome preview]

**Edge & Internet Explorer 11**

IE and Edge seem to have this invisible margin (not shown in the inspector).

[image: Edge preview]

The problem is when I view the buttons in the inspector, they don't have a margin. However, setting a `margin-left: -4px;` on the filter/load button can fix this; hence, the `@(isIE ? "margin-left: -4px;" : "")` above.

[image]

**Problems**

1. I don't want to have to add a special CSS rule that only applies to IE and Edge.
2. The right side of the load button doesn't exactly line up quite perfectly with the elements above it (it's inbetween -4px and -5px).

**Question**

Is there some CSS rule I can apply *always* that doesn't ruin the visuals in chrome but fixes then in IE and Edge?

I've added a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Angryr/f0jqrhvk/4/) that displays it. If you open it in chrome is looks correct, if you open it in IE or Edge it has a gap between the buttons. How do I fix this in a *non-exceptional* way?

Comment: In general use flexbox for that but your question seems to be too broad.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle that replicates the issue, I hope that helps make it less broad?

Comment: Now we know it is really a bootstrap question, not an expert, someone will help I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the gap is due to the "display" property of those elements. When two elements are set to "inline" or "inline-block", and there is at least one whitespace character between them in the HTML, it is not omitted the way you would expect with "block" elements. The intention is that you can insert spans or other inline elements inside a body of text, and respect the surrounding whitespace.

That said, it's not uncommon that you want to use "inline-block" elements next to one another, and not have this gap. There are 3 solutions.

1) set the "letter spacing" of the parent element to a negative value, and then set it back to normal for child elements. In your fiddle that would be:

```
div {
  letter-spacing:-100px;
}
div * {
  letter-spacing:normal;
}
```

2) Eliminate whitespace in your markup, so the tags are touching. It might look ugly, but that would fix the problem.

3) Use a different way to style the elements. For instance, use "display: block" and "float: left", or use flexbox as another answer mentioned.

Comment: Ah, okay despite figuring out a solution I was still curious as to why it acted this way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the best solution but I believe I have found one.

```
.input-group {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.input-group > span,
.input-group > input,
.input-group > button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

This appears to get rid of the gap between the buttons without affecting chrome in a negative way (still looks the same on chrome).

Stickers pointing out that it might be bootstrap related allowed me to find [this page](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) on google which lead me to this result.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0jqrhvk/11/) of the answer.